# Is this operation of limits wrong?

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I was taught that the limit addition property $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) + \lim_{x \to a} g(x) = \lim_{x \to a} \left( f(x)+g(x) \right) $ holds only when these limits by themselves aren't infinities with opposite signs, in which case I would end up with $\infty - \infty$, which doesn't make sense. I've found the following in the book Inside interesting integrals, section 1.6, it has a sum of two limits but this is $\infty - \infty$ because of $\lim_{x \to 0} \ln{x}$ so we shouldn't be able to apply the mentioned addition property, but I assume this is what the author did, as he added both logarithms together. Check here (used antiderivative and then split into two integrals. This shouldn't be allowed either because it's expressing a convergent integral as difference of divergent integrals):

[image: Limit addition property?]

He gets the correct result eventually but that doesn't necessarily mean the process is clean. I think this is wrong but I decided to ask since it would be strange to find something wrong like that in a book, so I wanted to make sure. (If this is actually correct please explain why)

Edit: Thanks to user, I was wrong when assuming the original integral was convergent. It turns out it's divergent by standard integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it is wrong, let consider for example

$$f(x)=1+\sin x \quad g(x)=1-\sin x$$

what is true is that if $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) $ both exist finite or to infinite with the same sign then the sum is equal to $\lim_{x \to a} \left( f(x)+g(x) \right) $, extending the sum also for the $\infty$ case with the same sign.

With reference to the example presented, according to the standard definition, the two integrals should be evaluated separetely and since each one diverges also the integral as a whole diverges. Refer also to the convergence definition given [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral).

Comment: Then is it wrong from the beginning because of writing the integral as a difference of divergent integrals? If this is always wrong to do, is there another 'legit' way to solve that integral for example?

Comment: The two integrals should be evaluated separetely and since each one diverges with different sign also the integral as a whole diverges.

Comment: Interesting. WolframAlpha states that it is divergent indeed, and the author provides $- \pi \frac{\sqrt{3}}{9}$ as a solution, together with a numerical solution. Do you know how do numerical solutions work and why would it throw the same result?

Comment: According to the standard definition the integral diverge but we can also proceed in such way the divergent part of the two halves cancel out giving a finite result. Probably this is what the author is doing here. But it not the standard way to evaluate it.

Comment: 'Often one is able to compute values for improper integrals, even when the function is not integrable in the conventional sense (as a Riemann integral, for instance) because of a singularity in the function or because one of the bounds of integration is infinite.' That's what I found in the Wikipedia article you showed. I'll take that as an explanation for what happened

Comment: I add definitely: I've checked definition of Cauchy Principal Value, and that's exactly what the author calculated. This is defined as the limit of the sum, which is what he did

Comment: @M364 Ah ok that’s fine in that particular context! But as noticed it is not the standard definition. Well done. Bye

Answer (score 1):

There are two things, Limit of the sum and sum of the limits. They are equal only both the limits exist finitely or when both of them diverge to infinity with the same sign. In the book, one diverges to positive infinite and the other one to negative infinite. So, sum of limits$\neq$ limit of sum.

The true limit is always the limit of the sum. So, adding the functions first to get a single function and applying the limit is valid.

The author has first added them into a single function and then applied the limits. So, that is a valid operation.

Similarly, as answered by @user, the limit $$(\lim_{x\to ∞}(1+sinx))+(\lim_{x\to ∞}(1-sinx))\neq\lim_{x\to ∞}2$$

The true limit is always the Limit of the sum, not the sum of limits.

Comment: I'm confused. Another user answered saying it's wrong

Comment: I have edited it. I hope this might clarify things

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Your idea is clear now. The equality does not hold in this case. The author ultimately computed (without stating it)  what is known as the Cauchy Principal Value, which is, as you might expect, the limit of the sum.